# WebView detect click in iframe

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView where I am loading a javascript that loads some content. That content is an html with an iframe.

It seems any click within iframe is not triggering calls to `WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);` The webview has set both `WebViewClient` and `WebChromeClient`.

A work-around I can see of is to call `getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true)` on the WebView and then within `onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)` assume the call was made within iframe and use some inserted javascript in order to get the iframe data. But that seems ugly to me.

So, the question: how do you detect a click within iframe loaded within the webview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have found what is the problem: I broke the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). A colleague that is doing web development pointed me in the right direction.

The whole document (containing the iFrame) has a different origin (combination of scheme, host name and port number) than containing iframe. As long as those frames (containing document and inner iframe) have different origins, they cannot communicate. That's why I am not getting calls to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

**EDIT**: It seems there is a way to overpass above security policy, but that comes with accepted security risk: Add the following header in the response that contains the iframe: "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:***"

Comment: @gunnar is it possible to play video now, i'm in serious need for some answer i find many but can't fit in my scenario.

Comment: @NitinMisra: What is the problem you're facing? Why don't you create a new question on StackOverflow, sent a new comment with its URL. In this way I can understand your question and also you have a bigger chance that someone else may know the answer.

Comment: @gunar Were you able to detect clicks after the access-control-allow-origin is set on the response?